# Putting a setInterval when a function called

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

```
var now = new Date();
var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 1, 20, 00, 0) - now;

function openAPage() {
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var myWin = window.open("http://google.com","_blank")
    var endTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;

    document.write("<br>button pressed@</br>")
    document.write(startTime);
    document.write("<br>page loaded@</br>")
    document.write(endTime);
    document.write("<br>time taken</br>")
    document.write(timeTaken);

    myWin.close()
}

function beginSequence() {
    openAPage();
    setInterval(openAPage, 5000);
}

setTimeout(beginSequence, millisTill10);
```

This is my JS code. I am opening a web page with `setTimeout` as you see. But after then I want to put an internal for example I will call `openAPage` function every 1 minute after `setTimeout` statement. How will I do it? Can anyone fix my code?

Comment: If you want to set another timeout you ... write another setTimeout call into your function?

Comment: Why are you using `var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 1, 20, 00, 0) - now;`? Try using `setTimeout(beginSequence, 5000);` and if this fixes your problem, then it's a problem the `millisTill10` code.

Comment: I don't don't which time is at your place, but `millisTill10` is 16 minutes for me... maybe that is why it is "not working"?

Comment: I get `-42723273` for `millisTill10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(startOpeningPages, millisTill10);

function startOpeningPages() {
   openAPage();
   setInterval(openAPage, 60 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: @ramazan murat Try my example.

Comment: @sje397 The reason why your code doesn't work is because the `startOpeningPages` function is undefined at the time of invoking `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Jacob. Nope, that's not true. See for example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/KnCWR/ ... Functions aren't scoped that way.

Comment: hey still doesnt work i will edit the code up pls check again Jacob Relkin

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: Function and variable declarations always "rise to the top" of the scope. In case of function declarations, the functions are even defined prior to their definition in the code (don't confuse that with function expressions, where function are assigned to a variable. These are undefined).

Comment: @ramazan: 'not working' isn't very helpful. Do you see any errors? If you put `alert('test');` at the top of the `openAPage` function, does it show?

Comment: @Ramazan : Looks okay to me. Are you sure whether you are sufficient to carry out some basic browser - js things?

Answer (score 0):

I realize there are a lot of correct answers already. I'll post this anyway for kicks :)

```
function() {
   var win = window.open("about:blank")
   var doc = win.document
   doc.write("Hello")
   setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60*1000)
}()
```

These are 2 of the my favorite things you can do in Javascript: Self-invoke a function (the ending `()` after the function declaration, and being able to access the anonymous function from within the function through `arguments.callee`.

This is better than `setInterval` in that the first process has to be completed **and then** 60s later, the second process starts. With `setInterval`, the process just keeps starting every 60s. 60s is a large interval where this wouldn't matter as much, but this usually matters a lot more with smaller times (in the ms ranges). Because it might end up buffering the second function to execute before the first one is complete.

Comment: Note that `arguments.callee` will throw an error in ECMAScript 5 strict mode: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/ You should sloooowly start to not use it anymore... sorry :)

Comment: Aww...makes me a little sad. But good link. Good stuff to know. Thanks!